# Cygwin intermittently loses it's mapped drives in /cygdrive

Tags: cygwin, virtual-machine, windows-server-2016, vcenter

So, I have a collection of Windows Server 2016 virtual machines that are used to run some tests in pairs.  To perform these tests, I copy a selection of scripts and files from the network on to the machine, before performing the tests.
I'm basically using a selection of scripts that have existed around here since before my time and whilst i would like to use other methods, so much of our infrastructure relies on these scripts that overhauling the system would be a colossal task.

First up, i sort out the mapped drives with
`net use X: \\network\location1 /user:domain\user password`
`net use Y: \\network\location2 /user:domain\user password`
and so on

Soon after, i use rsync to copy files from a location in `/cygdrive/y/somewhere` to `/cygdrive/c/somewhere_else`

During the rsync, i will get errors that "files have vanished" (I'm currently unable to post the exact error, I will edit this later to include this). When i check what's currently in the `/cygdrive` directory, all i see is `/cygdrive/c` and everything else has disappeared.

I've tried making a symbolic link to `/cygdrive/y` in a different location, I've tried including `persistent:yes` on the net use command, I've changed the power settings on the network card to not sleep.  None of these work.
I'm currently looking into the settings for the virtual machines themselves at this point, but I have some doubts as we have other virtual windows machines that do not seem to have this issue.

Has anyone has heard of anything similar and/or knows of a decent method to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I've been working on this all day and finally noticed a positive change, but since my systems are in VMware's vCloud, this may not work for some people.  It's was simply a matter of having the VM turned off and upgrading the Virtual Hardware Version to the latest version.  I have noticed with this though, that upon a restart, one of the first messages that comes up mentions that the computer is "disabling group policies".
I did a bit of research into this and found out that Windows 8 and 10 (no mention of any Windows Server machines) both automatically update Group Policies in the background, disconnecting and reconnecting mapped drives to recreate them.
It's possible that changing the Group Policy drive from "recreate" to "update" should fix this issue, and that the Virtual Hardware update happened to resolve this in a similar manner.